# Can't import global package in Node even though NODE_PATH is set?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to import a globally installed pkg located at /some/path. I have set NODE_PATH in ~/.bash_profile. I am able to do 'echo $NODE_PATH' and see my path in a terminal. However node 11.10.1 still isn't finding the pkg. From what I read here  https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/modules.html#all_Together require.paths should be initialized from this env var. However if I log require.paths, it is not set, console.log(require.paths) is undefined. How can I fix this?

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_PATH)

var i = require('promised-io')
```

exact error msg: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'promised-io'

Comment: What does `process.env.NODE_PATH` return? Is the variable exported in bash?

Comment: Please show the code where you're attempting to do the `import` and show the EXACT error message you get.

Comment: updated question with code and err. process.env.NODE_PATH is undefined. In ~/.bash_profile I have a line 
export NODE_PATH="/some/path/node_modules"

Comment: It appears your NODE_PATH environment variable is not getting set.  This something in the OS tools you're using, not something related to nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

Have had the same problem with node v16.14.0 as installed in Ubuntu 21.10. The environment variable `$NODE_PATH` seems to be ignored, and the global install path as used by `npm` (`/usr/local/lib/node_modules`) is not searched by `node`. For me I found two workarounds:

- Add `module.paths.push('/usr/local/lib/node_modules');` to the `*.js`

or if you don't want to patch other peoples tools but still want to provide global installed packets e.g. for multiple users of a build server, you can simply fix this with a symbolic link. Looking into [Node.js v16.14.0 documentation - Loading from the global folders](https://nodejs.org/docs/v16.14.0/api/modules.html#loading-from-the-global-folders) shows, that `node` still searches in `$PREFIX/lib/node` but no longer in `$PREFIX/lib/node_modules`. So we can solve this deviation between `npm` and `node` global default path by

- `sudo ln -sf /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/node`